# MySql.Data.Entity version 6.7.4.0 schema is not valid

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have tried to build my project and i'm getting this error

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 

Models.Context.StoreManager.ssdl(2,92) : error 0004: Could not load file or assembly     
'MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or 
one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the 
assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Any ideas anyone?

I'm using C# MVC

Comment: I wonder if this is another manifestation of this: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2051

Comment: I thought a bit more about this and I don't think this is related to the bug I linked above. The exception happens when loading ssdl. When loading SSDL EF needs a provider to resolve store types so it tries to load it using the name specified in the config file. This is when the exception happens so it looks to me that the version of the MySql.Data.Entity assembly you specified in the config file does not match the version referenced in the project and loading fails.